# how to programmatically create segue for use with Protocol & Delegate (swift 3 xcode)

Tags: ios, delegates, segue, protocols

I'm trying to send information between classes and ViewControllers. I've looked at protocols and delegates as a way of achieving this but, it seems I need a segue between the viewcontrollers to access the delegate. I'm not using a storyboard so I can't create a segue, as such I have two questions:

1. Can I create a segue programmatically between two view controllers? If so, how do I do that?
2. Additionally, if I have two classes in the same viewController and I would like to access data from one to the other, is using protocols and delegates the best method to achieve this or is NSNotificationcenter a better option?

Comment: If you aren't using a storyboard then you must be instantiating your view controller directly and then presenting it. Once you have instantiated the view controller you can simply set properties on it.

Comment: Sure, what would the code look like for setting the segue way Identifier using that process?

Comment: You don't have a segue if you aren't using storyboard. You just use `presentViewController:animated` or similar

Comment: If i don't have a segue, how do I use protocol and delegates? From all the tutorials i've seen, you need to use prepareforsegue to set the delegate for the process to work.

Comment: As I said, you will have the view controller reference already, so you don't need `prepareForSegue`. You can just set the delegate directly

Comment: Okay, so what would that look like. Something like this viewController.delegate = self ? An example of how this would work would be great, as i can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: @rob8989, you ca simply use property pass data from vc1 to vc2, and use closure pass data from vc2 to vc1 when come back.

Answer (score 0):

If you need set a delegate between another class if the segue is not used, You can create an instance of the secondViewController and with this instance you call call delegate
refer this Code:

> In **Swift**

if you are Presenting it modely,

```
let VC = SecondViewContoller()
    VC.delegate = self
    present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if you are pushing,

```
let VC = MeaasgesController()
    VC.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
```

> In **Objective-C**

if you are Presenting it modely,

```
SecondViewContoller *VC = [[SecondViewContoller alloc] init];
VC.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:VC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

if you are pushing,

```
SecondViewContoller *VC = [[SecondViewContoller alloc] init];
VC.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
```